# Is there any open source sdk like cam scanner in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios6, open-source, xcode4.5

Can anyone tell me about Cam Scanner?How to implement that in my app.
I have search a lot about this.Can anyone suggest me any link or sdks so that i can implement this.

Comment: look at this bellow links [simple-iphone-image-processing](https://code.google.com/p/simple-iphone-image-processing/) also check out some other answer from this bellow link.. [cropping-uiimage-like-camscanner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10477195/cropping-uiimage-like-camscanner) i hope its helpful to you..

Comment: thanks for your answer,can you please give me the link of any other tutorial?

Comment: yes mate why not see different books http://appfinder.lisisoft.com/ipad-iphone-apps/sdk-x0-multi.html?cat=productivity&device=iphone

Comment: i want to integrate the cam scanner in my app , i checked the above link also but didn't find anything helpful.If you have any tutorial or links ,can you please share?

Comment: mate see i search about that see this link http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/ipad-iphone-camera-scan-documents-pdf-iphone-ipad-2/ but i think this is not useful to you but i will search about it with good tutorial which is easy to understand :)

Comment: Thanks Paras ,i am looking for that,but didn't find anything helpful.

Comment: Also checked Simple-iphone-image-processing but that also not helpful

Comment: i think its helpful to understand it dude.. but its ok .. exactly what you want?? image Editing??

Comment: i don't want image editing ,i want document scanner.

Comment: yes and for that i post some links about that also i will post with docs of scanner when i searched with some detail

Comment: if u have something then please share.

Comment: sure mate i will post sure , i have idea about Image EelView for editing image but i think this is not useful for you so will search about it and post it soon